# BOOL being released?

Tags: objective-c, boolean

I have the following code:

```
 BOOL isFiltered = ((RTRepairOrdersViewController *)self.presentingViewController).isFiltered;

 *Use isFilteredHere*
```

If I run this code through the debugger and put a breakpoint on the first line, `isFiltered` is being set to `YES` but then immediately on the next line when I try to use it, it has reset to `NO`. What would cause this?

Comment: An object "being released" doesn't affect the evaluation of a property to said object (or to another object). Also, BOOL is a primitive and cannot "be released" in such a sense.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a breakpoint on the line where `isFiltered` is being set, you will break into the program before it has been set. Therefore what you are seeing interpreted as `YES` is actually uninitialized space. One you step past that line in the routine, the value is properly initialized with the value of `NO`.

Comment: If I mouse over the self.presentingviewcontroller.isFiltered, it also displays "YES". Is this also incorrect?